# C program gives an output different on different compiler

Tags: c, gcc, turbo-c++

I ran a C program and got different output on different C compilers. Below is 
my program

```
void main()
{
    int i=5;
     printf("%d%d%d%d%d",i++,i--,++i,--i,i);
}
```

ON boarnland c++ complier o/p is

> 45545

and on gcc its

> 45555

is it really compiler dependent or its OS dependent?

The arguments in a function call are pushed into the stack from left to right. The evaluation is by popping out from the stack. and the  evaluation is from right to left, hence the result.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the OS. I would say it was the compiler.

Comment: Combining effects and side-effects of different operations in to one terse codeline like this makes your code hard to read, IMNSHO.  I would avoid it for readability alone.  (I only use ++ and -- in well-established idioms such as for-loops or stand-alone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rely on the order of execution of side effects to arguments to a function. In this case the 2 compilers are executing the side effects in a different order, producing different results.

Comment: Thanks @qbert but i really don't konw about side effects ,i would like to read about side effects ...where can i read about it??

Comment: nd whts the order of execution in 2 compliler??

Comment: @AMIT: The "++" and "--" can cause side effects. These are things that happen after the value of the expression has been used. i++ means take the value of i, then increment i. In this case the incrementation of i is called a side effect.