# Different Run Results With Different Compilers

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc

I wrote a quick matrix multiplier in C. It compiles and runs fine on my MBA. When I compile and run on my schools Linux box though, I get stuck in an infinite loop.

This is my gcc compile

```
gcc -Wall prog1.c -o prog1
```

This is the version of gcc I have on my MBA

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 
2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This is the version of gcc on the schools server.

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/cEn9jbYF) to the code.

**EDIT**: Sorry! I get an infinite loop on the input verification. I've been using printf statements to debug my code but even still I have a hard time understanding why it gets stuck there. What happens is the for() on line 181 keeps looping after it encounters a '+' or '-'.

Sixteen command line parameters because it fills two matrices with 8 integers each.

I'm not absolutely positive it's a problem with different compilers or my code! I just figured that was it because I get expected results on my MBA but not on the Red Hat machine.

Comment: _Where_ does it get stuck in an infinite loop? Without knowing that, it will be very hard to diagnose the problem. (It's almost certainly not a bug in gcc 4.4.7, but a bug in your code that you happen to get away with in one environment but not the other.)

Comment: Firsr step: use a debugger to figure out where the infinite loop is happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C program gives an output different on different compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115628/c-program-gives-an-output-different-on-different-compiler)

Comment: Sixteen command line parameters ? Interesting...

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Rather than the wall of code, is there some reason you're not utilizing *both* ends of those pipes and just having the parent process *send* each child the respective row/col of the matrix multiplication they're responsible for? This would collapse all those launches into literally one for-loop.

Comment: `char str[3]`? Really?